# "Назад" в хроме и мозилле

Tags: php, yii2

Если кто в курсе, подскажите как привести редирект в Mozilla Firefox и google chrome к однообразию.

История:
Изменение тикета в yii2, по роуту orders/update. В обычном случае при get-запросе возвращается вьюха с изменением, а при post происходит обновление тикета и рендерится та же страница с flash-объявлением об успешном действии. НО вот что:

- Мозилла. При нажатии кнопки "назад" происходит переход на страницу с тикетами, в то место по-вертикали, где находится тикет. Удобно, клево.
- Хром. При нажатии кнопки "назад" происходит переход на страницу, назовем ее "страница со вьюхой", а уже при повторном нажатии "назад" переход к странице с тикетами, но в самое начало.

Причем если сделать кнопку "назад" и откатить в Href задать js history.back, то оба браузера отрабатывают одинаково и уходят на "страница со вьюхой".

Как привести к однообразию, желательно конечно как в mozilla firefox - так удобнее юзерам))